# How to add Camera component to Prefab assests

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

Hi,Im a newbie to Unity. May I ask a question, I want to add camera component into the prefab assets as shown in the picture but I cant, may I know how to solve this? (The problem is I try to drag the Michelle camera into the MichellePen camera slot but cant due it does not accept. Only if I put my character in the Hierachy then it will work but I had create a group of characters and do it as selection (for my character selection menu). If I dont remove those characters from hierachy, those characters will appear with selected character (user becoming controlling 5 characters). But if I remove those characters, then this camera will missing. I dont know how to solve this...)

I had tried by change the code but this code is referring to the youtube. I also had tried by applying the script to the character itself. It actually work, it can draw but when I press R key button to delete the line, the character will also get deleted.

This is the code for the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Draw : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Camera cam = null;
    [SerializeField] LineRenderer trailPrefab = null;
    

    private LineRenderer currentTrail;
    private List<Vector3> points = new List<Vector3>();
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (!cam)
        {
            cam = Camera.main;
        }

        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            createNewLine();
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            addPoint();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            if(transform.childCount != 0)
            {
                foreach(Transform R in transform)
                {
                    Destroy(R.gameObject);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void createNewLine()
    {
        currentTrail = Instantiate(trailPrefab);
        currentTrail.transform.SetParent(transform, true);
        points.Clear();
    }

    private void updateLinePoints()
    {
        if(currentTrail != null && points.Count > 1)
        {
            currentTrail.positionCount = points.Count;
            currentTrail.SetPositions(points.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private void addPoint()
    {
        var Ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(Ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("writeable"))
            {
                points.Add(hit.point);
                updateLinePoints();
                return;
            }
            else
                return;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have scene references in assets (prefabs) -> if you close the scene in the editor the according objects are unloaded and don't exist anymore -> reference is lost. This should actually do it `if (!cam){ cam = Camera.main; }` -> make sure your camera is tagged `MainCamera` (see [`Camera.main`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html))

Comment: If the camera is rather contained in the prefab itself  -> click on the `>` symbol in the Inspector to go into prefab edit mode and reference the camera there

Comment: Ok noted for for that, thank you for the advise